# What does it mean that we have a topology greater than another topology?

Tags: general-topology

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies) article I read that two topologies can be compared.

Suppose that  $f : X \longrightarrow X $ be the identity map, $f (x) = x$ for any $x$. Consider on $X$ two topologies $\tau_1 , \tau_2 $.

Suppose that  $\tau_1 < \tau_2$ . Is $f : (X, \tau_1 ) \longrightarrow (X, \tau_2 ) $ always continuous? If not, construct a counterexample.

Let us construct the given value for $x$:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        & f(a)=a\\
        & f(b)=b\\
        & f(c)=c\\
        & f(d)=d,\\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

We can construct the two topologies where $f$ is continuous (or is it not?):
$$\tau_1(x)=\Big\{ \emptyset, X, \{a,b\} ,\{a \}\Big\}$$
$$\tau_2(x)=\Big\{ \emptyset, X, \{c,d\},\{c \}\Big\}$$

But how can I check if $\tau_1<\tau_2$?

And if these examples are wrong, what are right examples and how can we see that one topology is greater than the other?

Thanks

Comment: You can't choose the function $f$, it has to be the identity function.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected now based on your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article uses "$\subseteq$" symbol, not "$<$". The symbol means inclusion, i.e. $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_2$ means "$\tau_1$ is a subset of $\tau_2$". Topologies are sets so we can obviously ask whether one contains the other or vice versa. Note that inclusion is a partial ordering on the collection of all topologies.

> We can construct the two topologies where $f$ is continuous:

No, your $f$ is not continuous with respect to those topologies: $f^{-1}(\{c\})=\{c\}$ which does not belong to $\tau_1$.

In fact given the identity $f:(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$, $f(x)=x$ you can prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\tau_2\subseteq \tau_1$.

> But how can I check if $\tau_1<\tau_2$?

This was supposed to be "$\subseteq$". But of course neither $\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2$ nor $\tau_2\subseteq \tau_1$ in your concrete example. As I've mentiond before inclusion is a partial ordering, and these two topologies are not comparable.

Comment: Thanks. Can you make an example with two continuous topologies and see how that relates to $\tau_1>\tau_2$?

Comment: But you still use $\subseteq$ and not $<$? I have to consider the case $<$

Comment: Take $\tau_1=\{\emptyset, X,\{a\}\}$ and say $\tau_2=\{\emptyset, X\}$. Then $\tau_2\subseteq \tau_1$ and now $f:(X,\tau_1)\to (X,\tau_2)$ is continuous. Yes, I still use "$\subseteq$" because that's the correct symbol to use.

Comment: Weird, my professor uses $<$. I will ask him. So there is no such thing as  $\tau_1 < \tau_2$?

Comment: The question is meaningless, in maths you can defined what you want how you want. The real question is: would that be a standard symbol for something well established? No. However there is no other real choice here: it has to be inclusion (potentially reversed). As for your professor he is just too lazy or weird to follow standard nomenclature. That wouldn't be the first time such thing happens.

Comment: :) Thanks, I will follow up

Comment: I just found that Kolmogorov and Fomin  use that notation $\tau_1 \leq \tau_2$. Is this typical for Soviet school of Math compared to Western school of math?

Comment: @Luthier415Hz I don't know, maybe. Still, it is widely accepted nowadays to use "$\subseteq$" for inclusion. Using old notation is confusing and doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: My Prof is Soviet-school prof, so I have to follow that, but at least I know now what that is. Thanks!